# which permission should I select in GCP IAM console while creating Service account JSON for container.clusters.get?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to deploy my containerised applications on Semaphore. I am using GCP for that. but whenever I run

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials demo \
        --project "${project}" \
        --zone europe-west1-b
```

It  gives error 
(gcloud.container.clusters.get) ResponseError: code=403, 
message=Google Compute Engine: Required 'container.clusters.get' permission

Answer (score 4):

1. First, you need to see what service account are you using when doing that.

To [list the account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list) in use, login (as yourself), [activate a service account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account), or [authenticate an application](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production), you may check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/). For example, to authenticate as yourself, use:

```
gcloud auth login
```

2. You can then add a role (that includes 'container.clusters.get') to that service account. The following roles from this [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes_engine_roles) have the permission

   - Kubernetes Engine Admin (roles/container.admin)
   - Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin (roles/container.clusterAdmin)
   - Kubernetes Engine Developer (roles/container.developer)
   - Kubernetes Engine Viewer(roles/container.viewer)
3. Sometimes it happens that you might need to create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) and inside, add individual permissions (e.g. 'container.clusters.get')

Comment: and sometimes you can get away with something like `kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=$(gcloud config get-value core/account)`