# Google Kubernetes Get Credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using:

```
sudo gcloud container clusters get-credentials clustername --zone zone --project project_id
```

to get credentials in **jenkins**, this works in **GCP jenkins shell**.

While migrating to **AWS** I have setup new **jenkins** where I am using same command (with same parameters ) but there it fails with error code :

```
(gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s)
```

Same thing happens when I run in my local machine.

PS : I am logged into gcloud with a different GCP account from the one in command

Could help me figure out the issue

Comment: Could you run `gcloud auth list` and compare the results ?

Comment: Thanks this helped, The Jenkins user was reflecting the changes made in shell, fixing that solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to  make sure that the service account you are using has the roles needed for container.clusters.get. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981033/which-permission-should-i-select-in-gcp-iam-console-while-creating-service-accou) on how you can do that.

If you are still receiving an error, you can [create a new service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts), then grant the same roles needed for it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but as mentioned same command with same parameters works in a different cloud instance.

Comment: The other instance may have the proper permissions @UtkarshSharma

Answer (score 1):

'Could you run gcloud auth list and compare the results', suggestion by Mario helped

The Jenkins user was reflecting the authentication made in shell, fixing that solved the issue